# How to install SAP HANA database server on windows 10?

Tags: hana

I want to have a local HANA DB on my windows machine.

Is it even possible? Is there a guide for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HANA server runs exclusively on Linux. In order to have a local installation on MS Windows, you can use a virtual machine run in e.g. VirtualBox or VMware Player etc.

The free [SAP HANA Express Edition](https://www.sap.com/cmp/td/sap-hana-express-edition.html) provides readymade virtual machine images, that can be imported into your virtual machine easily.

Alternatively, you can try and install the [HANA Express edition](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/hxe-ua-install-using-docker.html) in a docker container on Windows.

Both mentioned links come with extensive documentation.
Note also that regardless of the way you install SAP HANA, you will absolutely need an Intel x86-64 processor. AMD processors won't work as SAP HANA relies on Intel's extended command set.

Comment: Just to add to Lars comment, you can't use it with Windows Subsystems for Linux (WSL) as well.

So SAP HANA, express is your best option to get a local install as a VM, but make sure you have enough RAM on your machine (at least 16GB for the db server only, and 24/32GB for the db server + apps flavor).